# Bundling old-school concatenated JS using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project that has old-school, pre-module style JS for use in a browser. The JS consists of hundreds of components built like this:

Root:

```
(function() {
    "use strict"
    window.App = {};

    App.SomeNameSpace = {};

    App.SomeOtherNameSpace = {};
})();
```

ExampleComponent:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    App.SomeNameSpace.ExampleComponent = function () { };

    App.SomeNameSpace.ExampleComponent.prototype.func = function () {
    // Do some random things here
    };
})();
```

ExampleComponent2:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    App.SomeNameSpace.ExampleComponent2 = function () { };

    App.SomeNameSpace.ExampleComponent2.prototype.func = function () {
    // Do some other random things here
    };
})();
```

And the file layout would be something like this:

```
some-namespace/component.0.js
some-namespace/component.1.js
some-other-namespace/other-component.0.js
root-component.js
```

And the bundling process would be to concatinate all scripts in a single folder (namespace), minify the result and output it as a single bundle (some-namespace.js, for example). And then the website would output the scripts in the correct order so root.js would be run first (so that all namespaces are defined), and then the bundles with actual "classes" would follow.

There are no imports, there's no ES5/ES6 functionality in there, except for some APIs that are polyfilled, it relies on jQuery and some other external libs.

Also it's important to note that each namespace has its own bundle and not all of them get used in each page. Each app page picks and chooses the components it needs, only the root script is loaded in all pages.

How can I "webpack-ify" this in the least painful way possible? Since there are no imports, there are no real entrypoints and everything is is defined globally using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You change only the root, to expose `App` variable to the window.

```
(function() {
    "use strict"
    App = App || {};

    App.SomeNameSpace = {};

    App.SomeOtherNameSpace = {};

    window.App = App;
    // ----^  exposing App variable to window
})();
```

Then create additional file, let's call it `loader.js`, that will require all the files **by the correct order**.

Comment: The problem is that each namespace has its own bundle and not all of them get used in each page. Each app page picks and chooses the components it needs, only the root script is loaded in all pages.

Comment: You can make multiple entry point (as `loader.js`), each for page.